# Meaning of Ruby methods ending with "!"

Tags: ruby, string, methods, string-interpolation

I'm a newbie to Ruby, and so far have found the explanations for `!` a bit too technical.

Let's say we have the following:

```
print "What is your first name?"

first_name = gets.chomp.upcase!

puts "Hi, #{first_name}. How are you?"
```

What does the `!` add to the method? Does it mean that every time I use `#{first_name}` in any subsequent strings, all the letters in the name will print in upper-case? How is the code affected if I leave `!` out?

Please explain it in layman's terms if you can, as I'm still coming to grips with some of Ruby's technical jargon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Steve. What have you read on bang methods so far? I think that knowing that would help us answer in a different way and maybe find an explanation that works for you.

Comment: `upcase` returns a _new_ upcased string whereas `upcase!` changes its receiver in-place. The `!` method also returns `nil` if the string is already uppercase. In that case, you’ll end up with `first_name` being `nil`. You should therefore stick to the non-bang variant.

Comment: bang methods? This is the first time I've heard "bang" in relation to Ruby. I'm working through the Intro to Ruby course on codeacademy.com, and I didn't even know anything about Ruby ten days ago.  A phrase like "...upcase! changes its receiver in-place" is kind of Latin to me ("receiver in-place?").  That's why I'm looking for a simplified explanation for now until I get more comfortable with Ruby's jargon. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve : See [this style guide](https://www.w3resource.com/ruby/ruby-style-guide.php#naming).

Comment: @Steve the docs for [Calling Methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html) and [Methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) are worth reading. They explain Ruby's method related concepts and conventions, including terms like "receiver" and "bang methods".

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The practice of calling exclaimation marks `bangs` predates Ruby by decades. For example the `#!` combo is called a shebang in Unix. The folk etymology is that is comes from "Bang!" in comic books or that punch card machines made a particully violent sound when punching the character... all I know is that its a lot easier then saying exclaimation mark methods.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby method names may end in `!`. It doesn't do anything special by itself, but there is a convention on which methods have it (though it is not always consistent); thus, just learn the method `String#upcase!` (and how it differs from `String#upcase`) on individual method-by-method basis, with the convention being a helpful reminder.

The convention is that the methods ending in `!` are either dangerous, or change the object, or perform some other kind of change, or can raise an error where the other version wouldn't.

Specifically, `String#upcase!` changes the string it operates on. `String#upcase` makes a new string that is upcased.

```
foo = "test"
p(foo.upcase)  # => "TEST"
p(foo)         # => "test"

foo = "test"
p(foo.upcase!) # => "TEST"
p(foo)         # => "TEST"    ​
```

As described in comments, `String#upcase!` returns `nil` when no upcasing needs to happen, so you never want to reassign the return value of `String#upcase!` back to the same variable you tried to `upcase!`.

```
foo = "TEST"
p(foo.upcase!) # => nil
p(foo)         # => "TEST"    ​
```

RE: bang methods: [see here](https://www.computer-dictionary-online.org/definitions-b/bang.html)

EDIT: "receiver" is the object receiving the message (i.e. method call). In `foo.upcase!`, the object in `foo` is the receiver. In `"TEST".upcase`, the string `"TEST"` is the receiver.

"in-place"` means the object itself is changed. The alternative is to create a new object that has the changes you want applied, with no change to the original object. For example, if you have a photo, cover the bottom half with a piece of paper and take a photo of that, you did a crude censorship by creating a new photo that is missing the lower half (but the original still exists). If you splat paint on the original photo, you censored it "in place".

Comment: "destructive" destroys the original content, and is thus basically a synonym to "in-place change" (or mutation). "non-destructive" way is the "make a new object" way.

Comment: Thank you. It would be helpful if you parsed the following for me. It's an explanation concerning ! and destructive methods, but I'm still trying to grasp the terminology. Here's the sentence:     "The use of a ! in a method name is just a convention for methods that mutate their calling object and/or one or more of the arguments passed to the method."  Let's use "name = gets.chomp.capitalize!". What is the "calling object?" What are the "arguments" passed to the method? I understand arguments in the command line interface but hadn't come across that term with Ruby until today. Thanks.

Comment: As discussed previously, `name = gets.chomp.capitalize!` is bad code; use `name = gets.chomp.capitalize` or `name = gets; name.chomp!; name.capitalize!`. The receiver in the first case is the string returned from `gets`; in the second case, the contents of the `name` variable. In this code, there are no arguments (also called parameters); but you could write `"it".capitalize(:turkic)`, where `"it"` is a receiver, and `:turkic` the single parameter. Also, since Ruby does not force parentheses, `puts "hi"` is basically equivalent to `puts("hi")` - `"hi"` being a parameter.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that there are core methods that alter the receiver that are not "bang" methods (that is, whose names do not end with an exclamation mark). A few examples are [Array#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-append), [Array#clear](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-clear), [Array#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-replace), [String#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-replace) and [Hash#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-replace).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed. Not 100% consistent.

Comment: [Matz's quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609725/2483313) about these kinds of methods: _"The bang (!) does not mean "destructive" nor lack of it mean non destructive either. The bang sign means "the bang version is more dangerous than its non bang counterpart; handle with care". Since Ruby has a lot of "destructive" methods, if bang signs follow your opinion, every Ruby program would be full of bangs, thus ugly."_

Comment: Ok, great. That's helpful. I think half the battle of learning Ruby (or any programming language) is acclimating oneself to the terminology.  Thank you again.

Comment: Amadan, your use of the photograph analogy was very helpful. THAT'S the kind of thing I'm looking for as I learn Ruby. Do you happen to know of any books/websites/etc. that teach Ruby this way?

Answer (score 3):

> What does the `!` add to the method?

Nothing. The `!` is simply part of the message name, just like the `u`, the `p`, the `c`, the `a`, the `s`, and the `e` are. It does not change anything about the message.

> How is the code affected if I leave `!` out?

Then you are simply sending a different message.

There is absolutely no difference whatsoever between `upcase` and `upcase!` or between `foo` and `bar`. They are just message names. If you write `foo`, then you send message `foo`, if you write `bar`, then you send message `bar`, if you write `upcase`, then you send message `upcase` (which in your case will be dispatched to the method [`String#upcase`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-upcase)), if you write `upcase!`, then you send message `upcase!` (which in your case will be dispatched to the method [`String#upcase!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-upcase-21)).

There is absolutely nothing special about message names ending in `!`, just like there is absolutely nothing special about message names ending in `?`, just like there is absolutely nothing special about message names ending in `a` or `b` or `c`.

There *are*, however, some *conventions*. In particular, the convention is:

If you have a *pair* of methods that both do *more or less the same thing*, then the one that is *more surprising* is named with a `!`.

That's it. That is all there is to it.

For example, there are the methods [`Process::exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-exit) and [`Process::exit!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-exit-21). They both do the same thing (terminate the process), but one of them *skips running the installed exit handlers*.

Since they both do the same thing, they could both be named "exit", but of course, you can't have two methods with the same name (on the same receiver). Therefore, we need to somehow distinguish between the two. We could come up with a completely different name for one of the two, but that would also be annoying.

So, instead, we add a `!` to one of the two methods. Now, the question is: which one of the two do we add the `!` to? Based on our convention, the "more surprising" one should get the `!`. The Ruby developers chose the one which ignores the exit handlers, which I think is the right choice: the whole point of exit handlers is that they get run when you exit, so a method that exits without running the exit handlers is surprising, and therefore should be marked with a `!`.

Note that *none* of this has anything to do with "destructive" or "mutation". `Process::exit!` doesn't mutate anything and it doesn't destroy anything. Note also that we *only* use the `!` to mark the *more surprising* method of a *pair* of methods. There should never be a method named `foo!` when there is not also a method named `foo`.

In particular, the fact that a method does *not* have a `!` does not tell you anything about the method. And the only thing that a method that *does* have a `!` tells you is that there are two methods, and you should probably check the documentation to make sure that you understand what these two methods do and what the "surprise" is that the `!` is warning you about. That's it.